# How can I efficiently store the contents of a VolatileImage between frames?

Tags: java, performance, java-2d

I'm making a game in Java and enjoying the speedup that [VolatileImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html) offers. I'd like to include an effect in my game that makes objects linger and fade in their old positions after moving away, much like the motion blur imitation described in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnGY4yV9Keo). The method involved in that video involves changing the screen-clearing (which occurs every frame) from opaque to partially transparent. This method is perfect except that it won't work for VolatileImages, since their memory contents could be lost at any time.

Using VolatileImage.[getSnapshot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html#getSnapshot%28%29) solves this problem, since you can save the image contents between frames in case they're lost. But this means a new image is created each frame, and if we assume 1920x1080 resolution, that's about 8 MB of memory allocation per frame. I'm hoping for a way to get around this, either by somehow writing the snapshot to pre-allocated memory or by achieving this effect in some other way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a fading animation for each object and play it at the old position?

Comment: Also you can use interpolation.

Comment: @Sri Yes I could, but consider the effort and performance cost of creating an animation for every object in the game. And if an object is animated (i.e. its look changes from frame to frame, not just its location), I would have to create a separate fading animation for each possible state.

Comment: Another option. Keep a cache system and create the volatile image whenever lost from the buffered image in the cache. Isn't it better?

Comment: @Sri Yes, that's what I meant by using getSnapshot(), but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve allocating so much memory each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating an accelerated BufferedImage like so:

```
private static BufferedImage renderImg = device.getDefaultConfiguration().
        createCompatibleImage(
                    device.getDisplayMode().getWidth(),
                    device.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
static {
    renderImg.setAccelerationPriority(1);
}
```